# Delete the first index of array string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i delete the first index(0) of a string[] array?
Can't find array.RemoveAt(0);
[image]

Comment: Consider using a List<string> if you have frequent adds/removes. It's a lot better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in .NET have a fixed length, so you can't simply add or remove elements at a given location. You'd need to create a new array. The easiest way would probably be to use a little Linq:

```
urlexploded = urlexploded.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

But you may not *need* an array. If you refactor your code so that `urlexploded` is a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as expected, or if you can make it an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just drop the `ToArray` at the end.